# Add or remove element in the middle of list (Scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, r5rs

Is it possible to add or remove elements in the middle of a linked list in Scheme? I can't seem to think of a way doing this with car/cdr/cons, but I reccon there must be a way to this.

If I have a list '(1 3 5 6), and I need to put in 4 between 5 and 6 for example, is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an element at a given position was done in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29125472/201359). Removing an element at a given position is similar:

```
(define (delete-at k lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((zero? k)
         (cdr lst))
        (else
         (cons (car lst)
               (delete-at (sub1 k) (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: Will this give a new list, or alter the existing one?

Comment: @user16655 this (as is the case with most list procedures in Scheme) will return a new list

Answer (score 0):

Here are two versions:

```
; list-insert : value index list -> list
;   return list where the ith element is x
(define (list-insert x i xs)
  (if (= i 0)
      (cons x xs)
      (cons (first xs) (list-insert x (- i 1) (rest xs)))))

(define (list-insert/version2 x i xs)
  (define-values (before after) (split-at xs i))
  (append before (list x) after))

(list-insert/version2 'x 2 '(a b c d))
(list-insert          'x 2 '(a b c d))
```

Both versions will allocate a new list. For large lists it will become inefficient.